# How to divide query in Controller?

Tags: php, symfony

How to divide query in Controller?

I have:

```
private function getPeoples($andWhere = null)
{
    $peoples = $this->getDoctrine()
                  ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:People')
                  ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();

    return $peoples;
}
```

This working ok, but i would like add for this IF and andWhere:

```
private function getPeoples($andWhere = null)
{
    $peoples = $this->getDoctrine()
                  ->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:People')
                  ->createQueryBuilder('p');
                if($andWhere == true){
                    $peoples->andWhere('p.test > 5');
                }

                  $peoples->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();

    return $peoples;
}
```

but this not working - object is not null, but not have data. Why? In Symfony 1 this working. How can i make it in Symfony2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$peopleQuery = $queryBuilder
    ->select('p')
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:People', 'p');

if ($andWhere === true) {
    $peopleQuery->andWhere('p.test > ?1');
    $peopleQuery->setParameter(1, 5);
}

$people = $peopleQuery->getQuery()->getResult();
```

By the way, please do not insert literal values into a DQL query, use positional parameters together with `setParameter()`, as seen above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should do something like this:

```
private function getPeople($andWhere = null)
{
    $qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:People')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p');

    if($andWhere == true) {
        $qb->where('p.test > ?1')
           ->setParameter(1, 5)
    }

    $people = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $people;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I was a bit faster. ;)

Comment: hehe yeah, that's true :)